# input type="file" phonegap/cordova with Paperclip Rails, works in safari ios, but not in Phonegap

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cordova, paperclip, phonegap-plugins

I'm developing a cordova app with Phonegap.
I'm running the phonegap application on my iphone.
I have a form with a file type input:

When I use it with safari on my phone, it works fine - Paperclip on Rails uploads the image just fine, but when I use the phonegap app, it doesn't fire anything. It does not complain that the avatar is empty (I validate that field), but it's just hanging and I see no activity on the server.

Important: when i click on submit, it does not even fire the create action.
Also, I print the file DataURL location and get a valid "data:image/png;base64,iVBOR... etc.", which is exactly what I get when I do the same with the Safari on the phone.

I don't think I need to use the cordova camera plugin. I have access to the camera just fine with html5, so this can't be the issue. I also know it's loading into the input, because it's not complaining it's empty, so what is going on here?

Any ideas?

Comment: are you using xcode 7?

Comment: Yes. it's ok, I'm just going to create an ionic app, so this will not be an issue...

Comment: and why do you think using ionic will fix this issue? do the input type file works or only the form submit fails?

Comment: I actually resolved this issue with FileReader for mobile browsers and plan to use native access to camera with ionic/phonegap/cordova, they are all really Cordova.